# Listview only displays one record from XML

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, listview, data-binding

Alright. First-time here and I have a pretty basic question.

I have an external XML stored..somehere. Let's say desktop.

XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<Incidents>
    <Incident>    
        <IncidentNumber>4</IncidentNumber>    
        <Summary>4</Summary>    
        <Reason1>4</Reason1>    
        <Reason2>4</Reason2>    
        <Reason3>4</Reason3>    
    </Incident>    
</Incidents>
```

It has more "Incident"s than this but I wanted to shorten it up.

In XAML, I am trying to display these data on ListView, like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="lst_data" Height="290" Margin="10,29,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="484" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFDADADA" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource IncidentProvider}}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=//Incident/IncidentNumber}" Header="Number"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=//Incident/Summary}" Header="Summary"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=//Incident/Reason1}" Header="Reason 1"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=//Incident/Reason2}" Header="Reason 2"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=//Incident/Reason3}" Header="Reason 3"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

This, in a way, works but brings and displays only the first record, not the rest. I tried other things I found on this site (like putting XML in project directory or using DataContext on Grid Listview resides in), none worked.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Thank you and sorry for taking your time with such a basic question.<

EDIT: With Superman's suggestion, it is like this now:

[Latest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N3Zr.png)

Comment: Please put a full working example so we can see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I tried next:

**MainWindows.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
            xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
            xmlns:model="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="1200">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="IncidentTemplate" DataType="model:IncidentsIncident">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IncidentNumber}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Summary}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Reason1}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Reason2}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Reason3}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="lst_data" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource IncidentTemplate}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number" Binding="{Binding IncidentNumber}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Summary" Binding="{Binding Summary}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Reason 1" Binding="{Binding Reason1}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Reason 2" Binding="{Binding Reason2}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Reason 3" Binding="{Binding Reason3}" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindows.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Xml;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public List<IncidentsIncident> ItemCollection { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("..\\..\\Incidents.xml");

            ItemCollection = new List<IncidentsIncident>();
            foreach (XmlElement item in doc.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().FirstOrDefault().ChildNodes)
            {
                ItemCollection.Add(new IncidentsIncident()
                {
                    IncidentNumber = byte.Parse(item.ChildNodes[0].InnerText),
                    Summary = byte.Parse(item.ChildNodes[1].InnerText),
                    Reason1 = byte.Parse(item.ChildNodes[2].InnerText),
                    Reason2 = byte.Parse(item.ChildNodes[3].InnerText),
                    Reason3 = byte.Parse(item.ChildNodes[4].InnerText)
                });
            }
            lst_data.ItemsSource = ItemCollection;
        }
    }
}
```

And the model:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class IncidentsIncident
{

    private byte incidentNumberField;

    private byte summaryField;

    private byte reason1Field;

    private byte reason2Field;

    private byte reason3Field;

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte IncidentNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.incidentNumberField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.incidentNumberField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte Summary
    {
        get
        {
            return this.summaryField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.summaryField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte Reason1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.reason1Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.reason1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte Reason2
    {
        get
        {
            return this.reason2Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.reason2Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte Reason3
    {
        get
        {
            return this.reason3Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.reason3Field = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for the total number of data only. For example, I have 4 "Incidents" with the numbers of 1,2,3,4 in XML. Each Incident has the same data within itselves. Incident number 1 has a summary value of 1, reason1 value of 1 etc.

Now, listview correctly gets 4 records but displays all lines as "1".

You can see it in the original post as an edit.

Comment: @Eldgrimr I`ve updated the answer. It does not do all in the xaml but also in the code behind (or view mode what ever you work with).
I`ve tested it and it works.

Comment: Hello Superman.

Thank you for your time and effort. This works. I'll play around this a little bit. 

Have a nice day!

Comment: @Eldgrimr Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

If you use the normal Binding.Path is should bind to the properties of the DataContext object which should be a [XmlElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.aspx) so just try {Binding Name}